# Measure amount of clipping

Tags: python, audio, audio-analysis

Can anyone point me to a command-line tool or Python module that measures the amount of clipping in an audio file? For example something comparable to http://www.ber-sd.com/dl_clipping.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
sox testt.wav -n stats
```

Where the value *Pk count* returns the amount of clipping.